# How to duplicate two displays of three in total in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

Two displays, which I want to make mirror, have the same resolution (1920x1080). One of them is TV on a wall :) It's not very comfortable to move content to TV each time, because it's behind me. I don't watch it when I use the first 1080p display so it would be better, if it just copies the other one.

There is "mirror" option in standart GUI, but it's for all displays (I want for 2 of 3).